# Export Avro file using Sqoop to Oracle

Tags: sqoop, avro, hortonworks-data-platform

We are using hortonworks distro and on sqoop 1.4.6. I am trying to load an Oracle table with an Avro file using sqoop export but fails with the following stacktrace

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: 'Objavro.schema��{"type":"record"'
    at HADOOP_CLAIMS.__loadFromFields(HADOOP_CLAIMS.java:208)
    at HADOOP_CLAIMS.parse(HADOOP_CLAIMS.java:156)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:470)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:739)
    at HADOOP_CLAIMS.__loadFromFields(HADOOP_CLAIMS.java:205)
```

Looks like its trying to use TextExportMapper instead of AvroExportMapper. I found this issue that should have addressed this problem in version 1.4.5 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1283

Any idea why this is continuing to happen in sqoop 1.4.6? Is there a different component that needs to be patched as well?

Comment: whats the sqoop statement used

Comment: `sqoop export --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ora_host>" --username <username> --password <pwd> --export-dir <dir> --table <table_name> --update-key <pk> --update-mode allowinsert`